# TFS 2013 default template build installshield project

Tags: installshield

Using the TFS 2013 default template, I am trying to build a VS 2012 installshield project. After building the project in TFS, I am getting only ***setup.exe*** in the drop folder; in the VS build, I get an ***.msi*** file as well.

Can anybody tell me how to get both setup.exe and .msi file in drop location through TFS build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the configuration in the solution, right click on solution and then configuration manager.
Ensure that build is ticked for platform / configuration you are using in your tfs build

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have changed the configuration manager for the solution. In the configuration I changed it to DVD-5 for release configuration, so that I got the msi also.